# Deep Learning: Should I dot product (input, weight) or dot(weight, input)? Does it even matters?

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

I've been following through [Neural Networks from Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEWy9vZcxW4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcjD5BAw2DxE6OF2tius3V3&index=4&ab_channel=sentdex) and found that the author switches the order of dot(input, weight) from time to time. The calculation shows that the dot product gives different answers, but does it matters when performing deep learning?

```
input = generate_2d_random_numbers_to_list(3, 4)
weight = generate_2d_random_numbers_to_list(4, 3)

print(np.dot(input , weight ))
print(np.dot(weight , input ))
```

Outputs:

```
[[-0.17752432  0.8954122   0.90645726]
 [ 0.63064018  0.67478076 -0.28574945]
 [ 0.31089983  1.3015615  -0.26077905]]
[[-0.58014457 -0.86012428 -0.6136864  -0.66298195]
 [ 0.22580815  1.3400082   1.30939685  0.89712584]
 [ 0.80068436  0.46175544  0.06031708  0.43434225]
 [ 0.18267677 -0.04059971 -0.5704223  -0.5837033 ]]
```

Comment: Because multiplication is commutative (and addition is commutative and associative), dot products are commutative (also termed "symmetric" in this context).  It looks like `np.dot` carries out *matrix multiplication* and of course the order matters, because even the dimensions of the results differ!

Comment: Yes, whuber is right that `np.dot` is for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the property of Matrix multiplcation. Any advice on the "conventional way" of multiplying `weight` and `input` in writing a neural network?